# How to unit test express router calls to a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I am simply trying to test the the userController gets called once the get route is requested.  I've seen a couple of other questions on StackOverflow where the accepted answer is to use supertest, but the solutions generally feel more like integration tests than unit tests.

Am I thinking about this wrong and should Express routes not get unit tested and just tested when I write my integration tests?

Any help would be appreciated.

controller.js

```
const userController = {

    get: (req, res, next) => {
        return res.status(200).json('hiding get request from controller')
    }
}

export default userController
```

routes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import userController from '../controllers/users';
const userRouter = express.Router();


userRouter.get('/', userController.get)


export default userRouter;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [supertest documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)
it states: Super-agent driven library for testing node.js HTTP servers using a fluent API.
So you can use it for both ubit testing and integration testing. Which is what is even on an academic level a controversial discussion. As a thought:

> Unit testing is a testing method by which individual units of source
>   code are tested to determine if they are ready to use, whereas
>   Integration testing checks integration between software modules.

and here the problem starts. 
Take e.g. an ERP system consisting of different modules (Finance, Sales, CRM, ...)
If you look at a high level these are modules and in the view of a system architect integretaion test is e.g.between finance and CRM module. 
looking into the finance module, the modules are ledgers and cost accounting -sointegration testing on that level is between those modules. So looking into ledgers you have a booking and a reporting module so...
The only thing we can assume that is accepted by most progrmmers/developers commonly that a single simple report is a unit but the rest is purely definition and convention - wether on a level of an accepted standard or a definition made by the organization.
Whatever you call it or you feel about the only thing thats sure is test your application well before delivering.
So the only one to give a "correct" answer is you (and your team if any)